# Why sort on sorted non clustered index field?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table with ID, Name, and Date.

And I have a non-clustered index like,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_NameDate ON [dbo].[Test] (Name, Date)
```

When I run the query,

```
select 
    [Name], [Date]
from 
    [dbo].[Test] WITH (INDEX(IX_Test_NameDate))
where 
    [Name] like 'A%'
order by 
    [Date] asc
```

I get in SQL Server's execution plan,

```
Select <-- Sort <-- Index Seek (NonClustered)
```

Why the sort? Isn't the date already sorted in the non-clustered index? What would a better non-clustered index look like that doesn't require a sort (only an index seek).

(Can't use a clustered index as this example is a condensed version of a bigger example with multiple rows/indexes).

For example, I get the execution plan (with sort) for a table that looks like this,

```
ID  Name    Date 
 1    A     2014-01-01 
 2    A     2014-02-01
 3    A     2014-03-01
 4    A     2014-04-01
 5    B     2014-01-01
 6    B     2014-02-01
 7    B     2014-03-01
 8    B     2014-04-01
 9    B     2014-05-01
10    B     2014-06-01
```

Shouldn't the dates be sorted in this case?

Comment: The sort required because `where [Name] like 'A%' ` returns rows which starts with `A`, and you want resultset to be sorted by `Date` . It wouldn't require sort for `WHERE [Name]='whatever' ORDER BY [Date] asc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Date` column is not "already sorted in the non-clustered index", at least, not *by itself*. It is sorted *after* `Name`.

Consider the following trivial table data:

```
Name     Date
-----    --------
Allen    1/1/2014
Barb     1/1/2013
Charlie  1/1/2015
Darlene  1/1/2012
Ernie    1/1/2016
Faith    1/1/2011
```

Once you've sorted by `Name`, the `Date` columns are potentially out of order. Dates are guaranteed in order only for rows that have the same `Name`.

Your goals are at cross-purposes to each other. You want multiple names--so the data is best ordered by name so that the seek is possible, but then you want to sort by Date. How would you propose storing the above six-row table so that it is sorted by Date *for every possible range of names?*

If there is some kind of regularity or pattern about the ranges of names (perhaps, for example, you **always** pull names by first letter only) then there is a possible workaround.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test ADD NamePrefix AS (Left(Name, 1)) PERSISTED;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_NamePrefix_Date ON dbo.Test (NamePrefix, Date);
```

Now this query *theoretically* should not need to perform the sort:

```
SELECT Name, Date
FROM dbo.Test
WHERE NamePrefix = 'A'
ORDER BY Date;
```

Be aware that there are some likely gotchas with adding a persisted computed column like this: increased data size, the fact that such a design is almost certainly wrong in almost every case, that the proliferation of computed columns would be very bad, among others.

P.S. It is generally not best practice to force indexes manually--let the optimizer choose.